# How can I swap my two screens, left to right?

Tags: xorg, gnome, xrandr, monitors, multi-monitor

I pressed something and accidentally swapped my two screens. My left one is actually considered as the right one, and vice versa. How can I swap them back?

**Edit** - Specifically, I'm using Gnome, though we might also want to keep this question generic.

**Edit 2** - It appears that my driver isn't compatible with xrandr. I'm attaching log of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` [here](http://pastebin.com/wpNutkwp)

Comment: Your upload only has the first 49 lines (and the relevant parts are later). Don't copy-paste from an editor, just upload the whole file.

Answer (score 49):

Your desktop environment probably has a way, but you don't say which one you're using (if any).

If your display driver is compatible with the [XRandR extension](https://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR), which is the standard X.org method for managing display resolutions and arrangements, you can use the command-line utility [`xrandr`](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.xhtml). I think the proprietary NVidia driver bypasses XRandR, so if you're using it, you'll have to use a dedicated NVidia tool.

Run `xrandr` (with no argument) to see your monitor (screen) arrangement. You'll see lines like these:

```
DVI-0 connected 1600x1200+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 306mm
DVI-1 connected 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 306mm
```

This example means that I have two monitors called `DVI-0` and `DVI-1`, and `DVI-1` is at the top left (position `+0+0`) while `DVI-0` is to its right (position `+1600+0`). To swap them, I would run

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --left-of DVI-1
```

Comment: I'm using Gnome. Having some problems with randr - http://pastebin.com/rZEjdN4B

Comment: @ripper234: Your display driver isn't compatible with XRandR. What display driver are you using (not just nvidia/ati/intel, but which driver: nv/nouveau/nvidia/radeon/radeonhd/fglrx/…)? If you're not sure, attach the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to your question.

Comment: here's the log, thanks. http://pastebin.com/wpNutkwp

Comment: That swaps them around but now I can't scroll the mouse in the correct direction between them. When my mouse is on my right screen, when I scroll left, the mouse stops at the barrier of the right screen - it does not continue onto the left screen.

Answer (score 7):

I use Ubuntu 20.4, and pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> accidentally, and fuzzled around with the several options. To switch back to my original setting I used:

1. press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>
2. selected "Built in only"
3. then pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> again
4. selected "Join Displays"

If this keeps it in the wrong order, use "External only" first instead of "Built in Only"

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 18.10 here with GNOME 3.30.2.
Just go to Settings > Devices > Displays.

The display arrangement can be rearranged, with simple drag-and-drop.

I had better experience doing this rather than adding `xrandr --output DVI-0 --left-of DVI-1` to my `/home/.profile`.

Answer (score 2):

I used the native Gnome Monitor Manager (from the System->Preferences menu) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where I found this answer, but it works for me `xrandr -o normal`

Answer (score 1):

I use this script for that purpose

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --prop | grep "[^dis]connected" | cut --delimiter=" " -f1> "$HOME/currentScreens.txt"
echo "Number of active screens:" $(< "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" wc -l)
if [ $(< "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then 
   xrandr --auto && xrandr --output $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==1') --primary
   xrandr --auto && xrandr --output $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==2') --left-of $(cat "$HOME/currentScreens.txt" | awk 'NR==1')
else
   echo "Nothing to do"
fi
```